# More on finite groups generated by involutions

Tags: finite-groups, involutions

Can finite groups, which are generated by involutions, be represented as a quotient of a Coxeter group?

Comment: Yes, clearly?...

Comment: It is a quotient of the free product of groups of order 2 which is a Coxerter group. What is not clear is whether it is a quotient of a finite Coxeter group.

Comment: Maybe depending on how one thinks of "Coxeter groups" it may not have been clear that they are the _universal_ groups satisfying the relations $s_i^2=1$ and whatever relations $(s_is_j)^{m_{ij}}=1$, if any. But, yes, they are universal, so, clearly (as @SamHopkins says) the answer is "yes" to the question. But/and possibly one is thinking of _finite_ groups and finite Coxeter groups, as Mark Sapir speculates? Then the definiteness of the "matrix" of relations is the criterion for finiteness (spherical-ness).

Comment: My question above is related to this: For every finite group $G$ generated by $a_1,a_2, ..., a_n$ satisfying  $a_i^2=1$ for each $i$,  consider the Coxeter group $C(G)$ with Coxeter matrix $m_{i,j}=$ the order of $a_ia_j$ in $G$. Is this $C(G)$ finite? This does not seem to be always true. Take an infinite Coxeter group $C=<a_1,a_2,a_3>$ with all $m_{i,j}$ not equal to $\infty$. That group $C$ is residually finite. Therefore it has a finite  quotient $G$ where every product $a_ia_j$ has order $m_{i,j}$. Then $C(G)$ should be equal to $C$. So the answer to my question should be "no".

Comment: Thanks Mark.  What I am curious about is the relationship between groups generated by finite (internal) involutions and groups generated by (external) involutions on another semigroup.  See, for example: "On groups generated by involutions on a semigroup" by East & me.  External involutions lead to internal involutions in a natural way.  Tom